# Why does anonymous user still construct a controller marked [Authorize]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have some code in my constructor of my controller that only works when the user is signed in.  I've marked the controller as [Authorize] and/or added the following to global.asax (in MVC4):

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

However, my controller is still being created, and thus an exception is occurring.  Is this by design, or do I have something set up wrong?  I'd like for the authorization to kick in and send the user to my login route/page without ever creating the protected controller.

Comment: What kind of exception is it?

Answer (score 4):

The framework cannot read the attribute until after the controller is created.  Thus, Authorize does not get called until there is an object to call it on.

Answer (score 4):

The controller must be created (by the `ControllerFactory`) before it's attributes (like `Authorize`) are examined.  So when the anonymous user tries to invoke an action on the controller marked with `Authorize`, the controller must be created.  If there is initialization code you need done only after a user is authorized, you should be doing that in the action that authorizes the user, not in the constructor.